# Horizontally and vertically scaling RabbitMQ consumers?

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, scalability

How do I scale RabbitMQ consumers in Ruby using the AMQP gem?

I read the documentation and came up with something that (seemingly) works
in a trivial example. The examples scale horizontally. New processes connect
to the broker and receive a subset of messages. From there each process can 
spin up multiple consumer threads. It uses the low level consumer interface 
described in the documentation.

Here's the code:

```
require 'amqp'

workers = ARGV[1] || 4

puts "Running #{workers} workers"

AMQP.start do |amqp|
  channel = AMQP::Channel.new

  channel.on_error do |conn, ex|
    raise ex.reply_text
  end

  exchange = channel.fanout 'scaling.test', durable: true, prefetch: 1
  queue = channel.queue("worker_queue", auto_delete: true).bind(exchange)

  workers.times do |i|
    consumer = AMQP::Consumer.new channel, queue, "consumer-#{i}", exclusive = false, manual_ack = false

    consumer.consume.on_delivery do |meta, payload|
      meta.ack
      puts "Consumer #{consumer.consumer_tag} in #{Process.pid} got #{payload}"
    end
  end

  trap('SIGTERM') do
    amqp.start { EM.stop }
  end
end
```

There are a few things I'm unsure of:

1. Does the exchange type matter? The documentation states a direct exchange load balances
   messages between queues. I tested this example using direct and fanout exchanges and it 
   functioned the same way. So if I'd like to support vertical and horizontal scaling does the
   exchange type matter?
2. What should the `:prefetch` option be? I thought one would be best.
3. How does the load balancing work specifically? The documentation states that load
   balancing happens between consumers and not between queues. However when I run two
   processes I can see process one print out: "1, 2, 3, 4", then process two print out
   "5, 6, 7, 8". I thought they would be out of order, or is the channel itself the consumer?
   This would make sense in accordance to the output but not the documentation.
4. Does this look correct from the EventMachine perspective? Do I need to do some sort of
   thread pooling to get multiple consumers in the same process working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Most of this is actually covered in the [documentation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) for brokers like RabbitMQ, but in answer to your questions:

1. For a worker queue you most likely want a direct exchange, that is, one which will route a message (job) to one worker exactly, and not to multiple workers at once. But this might change depending on your work. Fanout by definition should route the same message to multiple consumers.
2. Prefetch should be `1` for this time of setup. Generally speaking this asks the broker to fill the consumer's network buffer with `1` message until ack'd. An alternate setup would be that you have 1 consumer and `n` workers, in which case you would set the prefetch to `n`. Additionally it is worth noting that in this sort of setup you shouldn't ack until after you've done the work.
3. Load balancing is basically a round-robin between consumers. Which is why you're seeing everything sequentially. If each bit of work takes a different amount of time you'll see the distribution change.

I hope that helps. I haven't done anything with the Ruby AMQP library for a while — we rewrote all our [workers in Go](https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools).

Comment: Ivan, Thanks for the reply!

Follow up to your points:
1. That's what I thought (regarding direct exchange) but the example works "correctly" using a fanout or direct.
2. I'm confused about `1` / `n` in this case? Worker != consumer?

Comment: Hmm I suspect fanout might not be working as designed in the Ruby AMQP gem — one of my colleagues reported the same behaviour a while back but I didn't get a chance to investigate.

Comment: Re: 2. This was more of an architectural example, because each consumer comes at a cost to the broker (albeit minimal) you could use 1 consumer to fetch all the jobs, then allocate them to worker thread within your process. Something like celluloid would work nicely here, but as you're already using EventMachine that would do the job as well. In this instance you would want the consumer to fetch the same number of jobs as worker threads so they are always busy.